Mismatched batch size error when calculating cross-entropy loss in PyTorch using BERT Token Classification
I'm currently working on a project where I'm training a neural network model for word classification using PyTorch. However, I'm encountering an error related to mismatched batch sizes when calculating the cross-entropy loss.
I'm using a custom dataset and I've ensured that the input features and target labels are paired correctly. However, during training, I'm getting the following error:
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (6368) to match target batch_size (8000).


Here is my fine-tuning code:
# Train
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n_epochs = 3
val_acc_set, val_eval_dict = [], []
train_acc_set, train_eval_dict = [], []
acc_best = 0

for epoch in range(n_epochs): # loop through each epoch during model training
    model.train() # set model to training mode, enabling gradient computation
    torch.set_grad_enabled(True)

    total_train_loss = 0 # accumulate total loss during one epoch
    list_hyp, list_label = [], [] # store prediction results and labels for each batch to calculate metrics after one epoch

    train_pbar = tqdm(train_loader, leave=True, total=len(train_loader)) # use tqdm to create progress bar during iteration through training data
    for i, batch_data in enumerate(train_pbar):
        # Forward model
        # -> call function to perform forward step on model with current batch data
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
          loss, batch_hyp, batch_label = forward_word_classification(model, batch_data[:-1], i2w=i2w, device='cuda')
        else:
          loss, batch_hyp, batch_label = forward_word_classification(model, batch_data[:-1], i2w=i2w, device='cpu')


        # Update model
        optimizer.zero_grad() # set parameter gradients to zero
        loss.backward() # compute gradients of loss with respect to parameters
        optimizer.step() # update model parameters based on computed gradients

        tr_loss = loss.item()
        total_train_loss = total_train_loss + tr_loss

        # Calculate metrics
        list_hyp += batch_hyp
        list_label += batch_label

        train_pbar.set_description("(Epoch {}) TRAIN LOSS:{:.4f} LR:{:.8f}".format((epoch+1),
            total_train_loss/(i+1), get_lr(optimizer)))

    # Calculate train metric
    metrics = ner_metrics_fn(list_hyp, list_label)
    print("(Epoch {}) TRAIN LOSS:{:.4f} {} LR:{:.8f}".format((epoch+1),
        total_train_loss/(i+1), metrics_to_string(metrics), get_lr(optimizer)))
    train_acc_set.append(metrics["ACC"])
    train_eval_dict.append(metrics)

    # Evaluate on validation
    model.eval()
    torch.set_grad_enabled(False)

    total_loss, total_correct, total_labels = 0, 0, 0
    list_hyp, list_label = [], []

    pbar = tqdm(valid_loader, leave=True, total=len(valid_loader))
    for i, batch_data in enumerate(pbar):
        batch_seq = batch_data[-1]

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
          loss, batch_hyp, batch_label = forward_word_classification(model, batch_data[:-1], i2w=i2w, device='cuda')
        else:
          loss, batch_hyp, batch_label = forward_word_classification(model, batch_data[:-1], i2w=i2w, device='cpu')

        # Calculate total loss
        valid_loss = loss.item()
        total_loss = total_loss + valid_loss

        # Calculate evaluation metrics
        list_hyp += batch_hyp
        list_label += batch_label
        metrics = ner_metrics_fn(list_hyp, list_label)

        pbar.set_description("VALID LOSS:{:.4f} {}".format(total_loss/(i+1), metrics_to_string(metrics)))

    metrics = ner_metrics_fn(list_hyp, list_label)
    print("(Epoch {}) VALID LOSS:{:.4f} {}".format((epoch+1),
        total_loss/(i+1), metrics_to_string(metrics)))

    ### add some codes start from her
    val_acc_set.append(metrics["ACC"])
    val_eval_dict.append(metrics)

    ### Compare and save the best model
    if metrics["ACC"] > acc_best:
      bestmodel = model
      bestepoch = epoch+1
      torch.save(bestmodel, f'{parent_directory}/bestmodel.pth')
      print("BEST MODEL FROM EPOCH {}". format((epoch+1)))
      acc_best = metrics["ACC"]

# Plotting training and validation accuracies
epochs = range(1, n_epochs + 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.plot(epochs, train_acc_set, label='Train Accuracy', marker='o')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc_set, label='Validation Accuracy', marker='o')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracies')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


Full error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ccc19f95b085> in <cell line: 8>()
     18         # -> memanggil fungsi u/ melakukan langkan maju pada model dgn batch data yg ada
     19         if torch.cuda.is_available():
---> 20           loss, batch_hyp, batch_label = forward_word_classification(model, batch_data[:-1], i2w=i2w, device='cuda')
     21         else:
     22           loss, batch_hyp, batch_label = forward_word_classification(model, batch_data[:-1], i2w=i2w, device='cpu')

7 frames
/content/drive/MyDrive/Tuning Sendiri IndoNLP/indonlu/utils/forward_fn.py in forward_word_classification(model, batch_data, i2w, is_test, device, **kwargs)
     64 
     65     # Forward model
---> 66     outputs = model(subword_batch, subword_to_word_indices_batch, attention_mask=mask_batch, token_type_ids=token_type_batch, labels=label_batch)
     67     loss, logits = outputs[:2]
     68 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510         else:
-> 1511             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1512 
   1513     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1518                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1521 
   1522         try:

/content/drive/MyDrive/Tuning Sendiri IndoNLP/indonlu/modules/word_classification.py in forward(self, input_ids, subword_to_word_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels)
    104         if labels is not None:
    105             loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
--> 106             loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
    107             outputs = (loss,) + outputs
    108 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509             return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510         else:
-> 1511             return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
   1512 
   1513     def _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1518                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1521 
   1522         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
   1177 
   1178     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1179         return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1180                                ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1181                                label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3057     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3058         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3059     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   3060 
   3061 


I suspect that the issue might be related to the format of my target labels or how they're processed during the forward pass of the model. However, I'm not sure how to fix it.
Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
My full code is here and if anyone wants to see the dependecies file, the code is just as written in here
